# How to resolve type mismatch for "Connection => [A]" with Play-JDBC?

Tags: scala, playframework

I am building a relatively simple REST API, and I finally settled on Anorm to use for my db access library within the Play framework. However, I am having some trouble getting a basic list query to work. I am sure that this is a simple fix, but I have not been able to find any documentation / solutions for this problem. In other examples, the code is more or less doing the same thing with the `query.as(parser *)` function being called / returned last.

The problem is my function is (according to IntelliJ) finding a `Connection => Unit` type rather than my desired `Connection => Seq[MyType]` type. Here is my code:

```
case class MyType(id: Int, name: String, createdAt: LocalDateTime, updatedAt: LocalDateTime)
```

```
class MyTypeRepository @Inject()(
    dbApi: DBApi
)(implicit ec: DBExecutionContext) {
    private val db = dbApi.database("default")

    private val parser: RowParser[MyType] = {
        for {
            id <- int("mytpe.id")
            name <- str("mytype.name")
            createdAt <- get[LocalDateTime]("mytype.created_at")
            updatedAt <- get[LocalDateTime]("mytype.updated_at")
        } yield (MyType(id, name, createdAt, updatedAt))
    }

    def list(): Seq[MyType] = {
        db.withConnection { implicit conn =>
            val query = SQL("SELECT * FROM mytype")
            val result = query.as(parser *)
        } // Type mismatch error is showing up here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Anorm result is assigned to a `val`, rather than being returned, so the compiler appropriately infers that `Unit` is returned instead.

Remove assignment to `val result` and so `query.as(..)` will be returned (instead of locally assigned).

```scala
def list(): Seq[MyType] = {
    db.withConnection { implicit conn =>
        val query = SQL("SELECT * FROM mytype")
        query.as(parser *)
    }
}
```

Anorm query could be simplified as:

```scala
def list(): Seq[MyType] = db.withConnection { implicit conn =>
  SQL"SELECT * FROM mytype".as(parser *)
}
```